# Proving that $V=R$ in $ZFC$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Kunen's "Set Theory" on page 21, defines $V:\{x: x=x\}$ and the Russell set $R:\{x:x\notin x\}$.

In discussing $V=R$: Kunen presents this in the context of Lemma I.4.9 that "$V$ doesn't exist, and neither does $R$." He shows using Comprehension if we had a $V$ with $\forall x[x\in V]$, we could form $R$ as $\{x\in V: x\notin x\}$.

Does this actually prove that $V=R$?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define identity on non-existing objects?

Comment: The "F" in "ZFC" implies $R = V$ when both are considered as proper classes.

Comment: @user251257 Thank you for the correction, I'll edit that out so no one falls prey to my ignorance. Regards,

Comment: I'm a little confused by what your question is.  Obviously what you have written here does not prove $V=R$ (how would it?).  Is your question about what the statement "$V=R$" means (given that $V$ and $R$ don't exist)?

Comment: @EricWofsey HI Eric - It actually is I that is confused. Later on he says (my elaboration) that with Extension, Comprehension, Pairing, Union, and with the addition of Foundation, that using $R$ from the Lemma I mentioned and $R=V$ as shorthand for $\forall x[x\notin x]$, $R=V$ is easily proved. So you are right and my question as posted is deficient. With regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the fact that $V$ and $R$ “don’t exist” has nothing to do with whether or not $V=R.$ Instead of “they don’t exist,” we should probably say “they are not sets” instead for clarity, although it does literally mean they are not in our formal domain of discourse (at least if we are working in ZFC and not a class-set theory).

Quick review of what things mean. Given a property $\phi(x)$ (i.e. a formula in the first order language of set theory), we can (informally) consider the class of sets with this property. Here, the properties are $x=x,$ corresponding to $V,$ and $x\notin x,$ corresponding to $R.$

Sometimes for a given property, there is a set whose elements are exactly the sets with the given property. (For instance, the property $x\neq x$ is never true, so the empty set has exactly the elements with this property.) In that case we say “the class is a set”, or “it exists”, or whatever. But sometimes, we this is not the case as was shown for your two properties/classes.

Two classes being equal means one’s defining property holds if and only if the other’s does. For $V,$ the defining property is $x=x,$ which always holds (thus $V$ is the class of all sets) and for $R$ it is the substantially less trivial $x\notin x,$ which makes $R$ the class of all sets that don’t contain themselves. So $V=R$ means that every set doesn’t contain itself. Expressed in the language of set theory, it is the sentence: $\forall x(x\notin x).$

As I said before, whether this is true or not has nothing to do with the Russel’s paradox arguments for why $V$ and $R$ are not sets. If we have the axiom of Foundation, as we do in ZF, then it is true since Foundation implies a set cannot contain itself. If we don’t have the axiom of foundation, it is undecidable. There are consistent (relative to ZF minus foundation) “anti-foundation” axioms one can assume in place of foundation that imply $V\neq R.$ (Including simply taking $\exists x (x\in x)$ as an axiom, though there are more interesting options.)

Comment: Hi - I am happy to give you this bounty. It's illuminating insights like this that make math so compelling for me. I would appreciate it if there are any particular sources you might recommend that treat set theory like this, or how I might otherwise get this type of perspective. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew thanks for the bounty. Actually, I just started in earnest on set theory recently. (I like writing answers on stuff I've just learned, even if it means I'm wrong and get embarrassed sometimes.) The book I read that had the clearest explanation of these kinds of issues was actually chapters 1 and 3 of Kunen (but the old 1980 version). Devlin's the Joy of Sets also had good commentary on classes, metatheory and the role of well-foundedness, and has a chapter on non-well-founded sets. Also learn a ton just reading random answers from Andres/Asaf/Noah/otherrs on MathSE.

Comment: Thanks. Well, it's working. I'll follow your suggestions.

Comment: Why are you using the older version of Kunen?

Comment: @Andrew Found it a bit more approachable, especially on the more introductory stuff. Nothing wrong with the newer version, though. Really, both versions are forcing books, but the first makes more of an attempt at being well rounded, even though it annoyingly puts chapter 2 where it doesn't belong (just skip it at first, even the book says it's fine).

Comment: Hi again - Perhaps this might be of interest to you, I've been using it somewhat. I would characterize it as a "Baby Kunen." Maybe it's not advanced enough for you, although it's billed as a first grad text. Of course, with your mysterious moniker, it's hard to tell what level you're on other than: far out. https://www.math.wisc.edu/~miller/old/m771-10/kunen770.pdf. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew Was aware of the book’s existence, but haven’t read it. Will check it out, thanks!